# SFTP integration flow in spring boot

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement in sftp integration where to read file from sftp remote location and place in local directory and process the file with business logic and convert to response object and then send to another remote sftp location.Also i need to delete files in local directory and archive files in another local directory. Can someone help me here

Comment: Share the code so that people will get clarity on what you are trying to do.

Comment: See the [Spring Integration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp) and the [Spring Integration samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples); ask a more specific question if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks i am able to figure out